# Why are `import` statements giving back different instances in Webpack 4?

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

In Webpack 1-3, I was able to used `import` and no matter where I used it, the instance I received matched the original. In Webpack 4, it seems `import` will return a different instance if the files are in a different root directory.

- File A: `/users/someone/projectA/file.js`
- File B1: `/users/someone/projectB/file1.js`
- File B2: `/users/someone/projectB/file2.js`

In Webpack, you can use aliases so `projectA/` looks like it's in `~A/` and `projectB` in `~B/`.

I don't know if those aliases are important, but when using them along with files in different directories, I might do something like this:

```
// projectA/file.js
import B1 from '~B/file1'
```

And also this:

```
// projectB/file2.js
import B1 from '~B/file1'
```

For whatever reason, the instance of B1 is different in each file. In earlier Webpack versions, these were the same. Tools like `Enzyme` depend on these references being the same.

Has something changed in Webpack 4 related to the instance of each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a manifest to your Webpack config:

```
optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: {
        name: 'manifest',
    },
},
```

This will link up your entrypoints so they all share the same import references; otherwise, Webpack has no way to know that `B1` in one entrypoint is the same `B1` in another entrypoint.